# Ruby reverse histogram

Tags: ruby, histogram

So I'm new to ruby and while I was reading about histograms I had a thought. Is there was a way to have a histogram convert a number into a line of symbols? For example, 12 would be converted into ############.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can multiply a string by an integer in Ruby.

```
value = 12
result = '#' * value
=> "############"
```

So for [1, 3, 5, 4] you could do

```
[1, 3, 5, 4].map{|value| '#' * value}
=> ["#", "###", "#####", "####"]
```

Comment: I mean I guess that could work. But I was thinking of something more like for [1,3,5,4] it would say 1 = #, 3 = ###, 4 = ####, 5 = #####

Comment: I'm not seeing your point.  I've edited my answer to show how you can use the feature.

Comment: oh okay, I get it now. I'm sorry like I said I'm new to programming in ruby so I didn't understand what you were saying at first. Thank you so much!